# Deleting a row from Flexicious dataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flexbuilder, flexicious

In a Flex `DataGrid`, you can delete a row using

```
[Objectname].removeSelectedIndex();
```

But this function is missing in the Flexicious `DataGrid`. Is there any other way / function to delete a row in flexicious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to remove a row from the datagrid. Datagrid rows are generated according to the elements inside the .dataProvider (object collection)

To remove one "row" you have to remove the element in the .dataProvider.

Depending on what "type" your .dataProvider is you <> be able to do

```
  grid.dataProvider.removeItemAt(index);
```

Check

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/data/DataProvider.html

Comment: well the problem i am facing here is that i am having a check box list for each row. when i delete a row from dataprovider to reflect the change in datagrid i have to refresh the datagrid now when i refresh the grid the pre selected rows are also refreshed and they become unselected.

Comment: Then something is  wrong in how you defined the renderers and the data model for them. please post you code!